# Form submitting three times in react js

Tags: forms, reactjs

I have contact form that auto submitting three times. Form submission calling API in in different port. 
First form submission to URL - `http://localhost:3002/user/contact_us` with no post data 
Second form submission to URL - `http://localhost:3000/contact_us` its my current page url.

Third submission going to url  - `http://localhost:3002/user/contact_us` with all data and getting respective response

but don't know why its submitting form three times. below is my contactus.js component file, Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

=====================================

```
import React from 'react'; 
import DefaultLayout from '../Layout/DefaultLayout';
//import $ from 'jquery';
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 
import { contactRequest } from '../actions/signupActions';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import  validator from 'validator';



class Contactus extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        document.title = "Contact Us";

        this.login_errorMapping = {"100": "Your message has been submitted.",
        "102": "Name cannot be empty.",
        "104": "Email cannot be empty.",
        "103": "Hotel cannot be empty.",
        "105": "Incorrect email format.",
        "106": "Phone cannot be empty."}

        this.state = {name: '',email:'', phone:'',hotel:'',message  :'',nameError: '',emailError:'', phoneError:'',hotelError:'',messageError:''};

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this); 
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this); 

    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //====Frontend validation=================
        let error = false;
        this.setState({nameError : ""});
        this.setState({emailError : ""});
        this.setState({phoneError : ""});
        this.setState({hotelError : ""});
        this.setState({messageError : ""});

        if(typeof this.state.name === undefined || this.state.name === null || this.state.name === ''){
            this.setState({nameError : "Name can not be empty"})
            error = true;
        } 
        if(typeof this.state.phone === undefined || this.state.phone === null || this.state.phone === ''){
            this.setState({phoneError : "Phone no. can not be empty"})
            error = true;
        } 

        if(typeof this.state.email === undefined || this.state.email === null || this.state.email === ''){
            this.setState({emailError : "Email can not be empty"})
            error = true;
        }else if(!validator.isEmail(this.state.email)){
             this.setState({emailError : "Incorrect email address"});
             error = true;
        }

         if(typeof this.state.hotel === undefined || this.state.hotel === null || this.state.hotel === ''){
            this.setState({hotelError : "Phone no. can not be empty"})
            error = true;
        } 

        if(typeof this.state.message === undefined || this.state.message === null || this.state.message === ''){
            this.setState({messageError : "Message no. can not be empty"})
            error = true;
        } 


        if(error === true){
            return;
        }else{
            delete this.state.nameError;
            delete this.state.phoneError;
            delete this.state.emailError;
            delete this.state.hotelError;
            delete this.state.messageError;
        }
        //======End frontend validation=========    

        this.props.contactRequest(this.state);
    }




    render(){

        const style_1 = {height: '240px'};
        const style_2 = {marginRight: '15px'};
        const style_3 = {width: 'auto'};


        return(
            <DefaultLayout>

                <section id="content">
                    <div className="content-wrap">
                        <div className="container clearfix">

                            <div className="col-md-6 bottommargin">
                                <section id="google-map" className="gmap" style={style_1} ></section>
                            </div>

                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactFormModal" className="button button-3d nomargin btn-block button-xlarge hidden-xs center">Click here to Send an Email</a>
                                <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#contactFormModal" className="button button-3d nomargin btn-block visible-xs center">Send an Email</a>

                                <div className="modal fade" id="contactFormModal" tabIndex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="contactFormModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div className="modal-dialog">
                                        <div className="modal-content">
                                            <div className="modal-header">
                                                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                                <h4 className="modal-title" id="contactFormModalLabel">Send Us an Email</h4>
                                            </div>
                                            <div className="modal-body">

                                                <div className="contact-widget">
                                                    <div className="contact-form-result">
                                                        {this.props.resultMessage && this.props.resultMessage.status.map((msg, idx) => { 
                                                                 if(msg === 100) { return <span key={idx} id="succ_msg">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                                                                 } else {
                                                                      return <span key={idx} id="err_msg">{this.errorMapping[msg]}</span>
                                                                }
                                                            })
                                                        }
                                                    </div>
                                                    <form className="nobottommargin" id="r_contactform" name="r_contactform" method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>

                                                        <div className="form-process"></div>

                                                        <div className={"col_half " + (this.state.nameError ? 'has-error': '') }>
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-name">Name <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-name" name="name" value={this.state.name} className="sm-form-control required" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                            <span className={this.state.nameError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.nameError ? this.state.nameError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className={"col_half col_last " + (this.state.emailError ? 'has-error': '') }>
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-email">Email <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <input type="email" id="template-contactform-email" name="email" value={this.state.email} className="required email sm-form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                            <span className={this.state.emailError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.emailError ? this.state.emailError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="clear"></div>

                                                        <div className={"col_half " + (this.state.phoneError ? 'has-error': '') }>
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-phone">Phone</label>
                                                            <input type="text" id="template-contactform-phone" name="phone" value={this.state.phone} className="sm-form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
                                                            <span className={this.state.phoneError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.phoneError ? this.state.phoneError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className={"col_half col_last " + (this.state.hotelError ? 'has-error': '') }>
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-service">Hotel</label>
                                                            <select value={this.state.hotel} id="hotel" name="hotel" className="sm-form-control" onChange={this.handleInputChange} > 
                                                                <option value="">-- Select One --</option>
                                                                <option value="Wordpress">Wordpress</option>
                                                                <option value="Graphic Design">Graphic Design</option>
                                                            </select>
                                                            <span className={this.state.hotelError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.hotelError ? this.state.hotelError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="clear"></div>

                                                        <div className={"col_half " + (this.state.messageError ? 'has-error': '') }>
                                                            <label htmlFor="template-contactform-message">Message <small>*</small></label>
                                                            <textarea className="required sm-form-control" id="template-contactform-message" name="message"  value={this.state.message} rows="6" cols="30" onChange={this.handleInputChange}></textarea>
                                                            <span className={this.state.messageError ? 'help-block error': '' }>{ this.state.messageError ? this.state.messageError: '' }</span>
                                                        </div>

                                                        <div className="col_full">
                                                            <button className="button button-3d nomargin" type="submit" id="contactform-submit" name="contactform-submit">Send Message</button>
                                                        </div>

                                                    </form>

                                                </div>


                                            </div>
                                            <div className="modal-footer">
                                                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </section>

            </DefaultLayout>
        );  
    }
}


function mapStateToProps(state){
    console.log("View data :"+JSON.stringify(state.data));
    return { 
        resultMessage: state.data
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
      return bindActionCreators({contactRequest: contactRequest}, dispatch)
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps) (Contactus);
```

Comment: You're using setState many time followed, try to store the data you need in varibales and then call setState only in the end of operation. You may be in trouble because forcing a render with data on stage mutating. Remember EVERY time you call setState react execute validations and merge states. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-are-merged

Comment: And last you shouldn't mutate state directily as you do in delete this.state.nameError;  https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly